# itunes internal tester notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I've added an internal tester with Technician privileges and with no territory notifications. This tester has to test one of our apps, but he has received an email from apple notifying that another of our app has been rejected. I don't want this tester knows about other apps.

Is there any way to set that this tester never receives info (or notifications) about other apps he should not have access to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal tester accounts you add in iTunes Connect will always have access to all apps and can also change their notification settings.

You can try the following:

- Add a new user in iTunes Connect with an email of your own
- enable internal tester switch for the new user
- invite this user for internal testing
- receive the email with the invite link starting with `https://beta.itunes.apple.com/v1/invite/...`, but don't click it
- send that link to your tester
- the tester can use any Apple ID to accept the invitation on an iOS 8 device